# Render HTML in django template (not unicode but ASCII) 

Tags: python, django, templates

I understand that this is a little perverse, but I have a legacy database with some entries as formatted html. I'd like to just push this into my django templates as ASCII and let the browser display it.

Django kindly converts my fields to unicode, and so the browser displays the entire text `<p> </p>` etc. intact.

I was hoping that there might be a template flag `{{ obj.text|ascii }}` or something that might fix this for me - does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: "Render unicode as ASCII" is rather meaningless. Please change the title to something that better reflects what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with either unicode or ASCII.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/ what you want is:

```
{{ obj.text|safe }}
```

Comment: Excellent! Ta muchly. Now why couldn't I find that?